# Faster than if-elif statement

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am receiving Points in large number from a sensor in real-time. However, I just need 4 categories of points, i.e., top_left, top_right, bottom_left, and bottom_right. I have an if-elif statement in Python 2 as follows:

```
from random import random, randint

# points below are received from sensor. however, 
# here in this post I am creating it randomly.
points = [Point(randint(0, i), random(), random(), random()) for i in range(100)] 

# 4 categories
top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right = None, None, None, None
for p in points:
    if p.id == 5:
        top_left = p
    elif p.id == 7:
        top_right = p
    elif p.id == 13:
        bottom_left = p
    elif p.id == 15:
        bottom_right = p

print top_left.id, top_left.x, top_left.y, top_left.z # check variable
```

Each Point has an id and x, y, z parameters. This is an inbuilt class. I am just showing a sample class here.

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, id, x, y, z):
        self.id = id
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Is there any efficient way considering runtime of achieving the same.

**Answer:**
I am adding the results which I got from the answers. It seems that [the answer by **Elis Byberi**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47003070/1175065) is fastest among all. Below is my test code:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, id, x, y, z):
        self.id = id
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

from random import random, randint
n = 1000
points = [Point(randint(0, i), random(), random(), random()) for i in range(n)]

def method1():
    top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right = None, None, None, None
    for p in points:
        if p.id == 5:
            top_left = p
        elif p.id == 7:
            top_right = p
        elif p.id == 13:
            bottom_left = p
        elif p.id == 15:
            bottom_right = p
    #print top_left.id, top_left.x, top_left.y, top_left.z

def method2():
    categories = {
        5: None,  # top_left
        7: None,  # top_right
        13: None,  # bottom_left
        15: None  # bottom_right
    }

    for p in points:
        categories[p.id] = p

    top_left = categories[5]
    #print top_left.id, top_left.x, top_left.y, top_left.z

def method3():
    name_to_id = {'top_left': 5, 'top_right': 7, 'bottom_left': 13, 'bottom_right': 15}
    ids = [value for value in name_to_id.values()]
    bbox = {id: None for id in ids}

    for point in points:
        try:
            bbox[point.id] = Point(point.id, point.x, point.y, point.z)
        except KeyError:  # Not an id of interest.
            pass

    top_left = bbox[name_to_id['top_left']]
    #print top_left.id, top_left.x, top_left.y, top_left.z

from timeit import Timer
print 'method 1:', Timer(lambda: method1()).timeit(number=n)
print 'method 2:', Timer(lambda: method2()).timeit(number=n)
print 'method 3:', Timer(lambda: method3()).timeit(number=n)
```

See Below the returned output:

```
ravi@home:~/Desktop$ python test.py 
method 1: 0.174991846085
method 2: 0.0743980407715
method 3: 0.582262039185
```

Comment: Efficient in which way? Run time, readability, or time it takes to type?

Comment: @NickPredey: Runtime

Comment: That's as efficient as a control structure can get, I think

Comment: I'd use dictionaries for the `buttons` and the `id` -> `buttons` mapping.

Comment: Why are you making 100 random points but only keeping 4 of them?

Comment: @KlausD. More explanation, please. The `Point` class is inbuild and I can't change it. I just posted a sample code here.

Comment: @RaviJoshi not only you changed the question, not there is nothing that can guarantee that you'll get points for top_left, top_right and etc!

Comment: alfasin and @PM2Ring:  I don't need all the points. I just need 4 points out of them. These points are received from a sensor in real-time. Thanks!

Comment: @RaviJoshi if you're using the IDs as a criteria for choosing and the IDs are chosen randomly, you can't guarantee that you'll have a point with id 5 or 7 and etc.

Comment: @alfasin: I agree with you. However, these points are received from a sensor. It may be true that some categories are none at the end.

Comment: Does the Point class have a `__lt__` method?

Comment: Why do you think your solution is inefficient?

Comment: Your series of `if` statements in the `for` loop could be handled with what in some languages, like C/C++, is called a `switch` statement. Python doesn't have one, but they can be emulated fairly efficiently. See [**Replacements for switch statement in Python?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python) However in this case one is not really needed. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47004474/355230) below to see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dict to save objects. Dict is very efficient in key lookup.

Using dict is twice as fast as using if else block.

This is the most efficient way in python:

```
from random import random, randint

class Point():
    def __init__(self, id, x, y, z):
        self.id = id
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

# points below are received from sensor. however,
# here in this post I am creating it randomly.
points = [Point(randint(0, i), random(), random(), random()) for i in
          range(100)]

# 4 categories
categories = {
    5: None,  # top_left
    7: None,  # top_right
    13: None,  # bottom_left
    15: None  # bottom_right
}

for p in points:
    categories[p.id] = p

>>> print categories[5].id, categories[5].x, categories[5].y, categories[5].z  # check variable
5 0.516239541892 0.935096344266 0.0859987803457
```

Comment: Why limit the dictionary to those keys and have to handle exceptions for all other Point.id's? Just add every Point.id to the dict and only use the keys you are interested in?

Comment: Do you think that if else block is faster than exception handling? I did a benchmark and it is twice as fast as if else block.

Comment: No, just make a dictionary with *every* Point.id - don't restrict it and manage the restriction with exception handling. Subsequent code can just use the relevant keys and ignore the other.

Comment: We do not know how many points are there and try/except block does not have any overhead.

Comment: try/except block was useless. Key will be added in dict anyway. Your statement about managing the restriction was strange because it was not restricting it anyway. It made me think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using list-comprehension:

```
points = [Point(randint(0, i), random(), random(), random()) for i in range(100)]
```

use a loop and assign the points during creation:

```
points = []
for i in range(100):
    p = Point(randint(0, i), random(), random(), random())
    points.append(p)
    if p.id == 5:
        top_left = p
    elif p.id == 7:
       top_right = p
    elif p.id == 13:
        bottom_left = p
    elif p.id == 15:
        bottom_right = p
```

This way you get all done in one iteration instead of two.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the index of this array. It can be any integer number. Please check the question again. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that should be faster because it uses a single `if` to determine whether a `Point` is one of the ones representing the extremes based on their `id` attribute, plus the `if` uses the very fast dictionary `in` operation for membership testing. Essentially what is done it the `bbox` dictionary is preloaded with keys that correspond to the four ids sought, which make checking for *any* of them a single relatively efficient operation.

Note that if there are points with duplicate `id`s in the `Point` list, the last one seen will be the one selected. Also note that if no point with a matching `id` is found, some of the final variables will have a value of `None` instead of a `Point` instance.

```
from random import randint, random
from pprint import pprint
from operator import attrgetter


class Point():
    def __init__(self, id, x, y, z):
        self.id = id
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


points = [Point(randint(0, 20), random(), random(), random()) for i in range(100)]
name_to_id = {'top_left': 5, 'top_right': 7, 'bottom_left': 13, 'bottom_right': 15}
bbox = {id: None for id in name_to_id.values()}  # Preload with ids of interest.

for point in points:
    if point.id in bbox:  # id of interest?
       bbox[point.id] = point

# Assign bbox's values to variables with meaningful names.
top_left = bbox[name_to_id['top_left']]
top_right = bbox[name_to_id['top_right']]
bottom_left = bbox[name_to_id['bottom_left']]
bottom_right = bbox[name_to_id['bottom_right']]

for point in [top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right]:
    print('Point({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(point.id, point.x, point.y, point.z))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I like the coding style especially `Assign bbox's values to variables with meaningful names.`